# Run oraoop without installation

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

When you install oraoop two important changes are made:

oraoop-1.6.0.jar is kept in sqoop`s lib

In $SQOOP_HOME/conf a **managers.d** folder is created, inside which there is a file named **oraoop** which contains:

```
com.quest.oraoop.OraOopManagerFactory=/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/oraoop-1.6.0.jar
```

Now i want to bypass these installation steps as i do not have the permissions to modify things on the cluster. I have found a work around about the jar, instead of keeping it inside sqoop`s lib I can use:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/root/shared_folder/oraoop-1.6.0.jar
```

But for the second statement i.e:

```
com.quest.oraoop.OraOopManagerFactory=/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/oraoop-1.6.0.jar
```

I am unable to run oraoop without putting this statement inside sqoop`s conf. Is there any way to pass this configuration externally?

I am using HDP 2.1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--connection-manager` option

```
sqoop import (generic-args) --connection-manager com.quest.oraoop.OraOopManagerFactory (import-args)
```

Comment: can you elaborate please because this is not working. @franklinsjio

Comment: sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE --connection-manager com.quest.oraoop.OraOopManagerFactory --driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --username ROOT --password manager --table temp --target-dir  /sqoop/tmp1 -m 3

Comment: And the error?.. Also try with moving the `--driver` and `--connection-manager` arguments before `--connect`.

Comment: after changing the sequence of the tools as you suggested the exception it is throwing is no such method.

Comment: 17/04/20 03:50:06 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.quest.oraoop.OraOopManagerFactory.<init>(java.lang.String, com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions)

Comment: The jar containing this class is added in the `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: Try `sqoop import -D 
sqoop.connection.factories=com.quest.oraoop.OraOopManagerFactory  --driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE --username ROOT --password manager --table temp --target-dir /sqoop/tmp1 -m 3`

Comment: 17/04/20 04:20:45 ERROR sqoop.ConnFactory: Could not load ManagerFactory com.quest.oraoop.OraOopManagerFac‌​tory (not found)

Comment: The oraoop.jar is not in the classpath. Add it as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43232644/7303447).

Comment: I am exporting the classpath using export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/root/shared_folder/oraoop-1.6.0.jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142171/discussion-between-aman-saurav-and-franklinsijo).